# SQL Server :Resolve Blocking with concurrent write and reads

Tags: sql-server

I have two separate stored procedures using same table in SQL Server 2016.

One is writing to the table and the other reading from the same table.

The second stored procedure waits or gets blocked as the first stored procedure is writing data to the table.

Is there any way I can read the latest data without using `(NOLOCK)`? Or is waiting the only option?

We are using sentry one to track the blocking

Comment: the second stored procedure - is is called inmediately after the data is inserted or with which frecuency is this seconds SP called? - can you provide an example that shows the case?

Comment: Are the procs reading/writing the same rows? If not, query index tuning is in order to avoid blocking. Otherwise, consider snapshot isolation to read the latest committed data.